# How to checking for similar strings in a dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

I want to get the most popular subject of these students and I do not know how to tackle the problem in an at least kind of elegant way. I can't figure out how to check inside the dictionary. It should return the subject with he most common answer.

```py
student = {
    1: {"name": "A", "grade": 10, "subject": "sports"},
    2: {"name": "B", "grade": 12, "subject": "maths"},
    3: {"name": "C", "grade": 8, "subject": "german"},
    4: {"name": "D", "grade": 11, "subject": "maths"},
    5: {"name": "E", "grade": 6, "subject": "art"},
    6: {"name": "F", "grade": 9, "subject": "english"}
}
```

This is the beginning of something I already tried but did not know how to continue because I did not know how to look for the largest variable:

```py
for key in student:
  if student[key]["subject"] == "sports":
    favorite_sports += 1
  elif student[key]["subject"] == "maths":
    favorite_maths += 1
  elif student[key]["subject"] == "german":
    favorite_german += 1
  elif student[key]["subject"] == "art":
    favorite_art += 1
  elif student[key]["subject"] == "enlgish":
    favorite_english += 1
```

I do not know how to look for the largest variable in a good way...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post code.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework (but to help you when you are stuck). What did YOU try ?

Comment: A very simple outline: First, make a `dict` to store the likes for each subject.  Iterate over the `dict` keys, start from 1 and keep going until you get an error for a key not existing.  On each key, update the item in the likes `dict` to one more.  If the key doesn't exist in the `dict`, simply add it.  At the end, iterate over the likes `dict` to find which item has the most likes (or which ones tie).  BUT YES: We're not here to do the coding for you, you need to try yourself first.  If you did, then please post your code so that we can answer more accurately.  If you have the code, add it.

Comment: If you don't know how to find the largest variable, then you need to do some more studying and research, not ask folks here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Counter class from collections:

```
student = {
    1: {"name": "A", "grade": 10, "subject": "sports"},
    2: {"name": "B", "grade": 12, "subject": "maths"},
    3: {"name": "C", "grade": 8, "subject": "german"},
    4: {"name": "D", "grade": 11, "subject": "maths"},
    5: {"name": "E", "grade": 6, "subject": "art"},
    6: {"name": "F", "grade": 9, "subject": "english"}
}

from collections import Counter
favorites = Counter(d["subject"] for _,d in student.items())

print(favorites)
Counter({'maths': 2, 'sports': 1, 'german': 1, 'art': 1, 'english': 1})

print(favorites.most_common(2))
[('maths', 2), ('sports', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating a defaultdict that contains the number of times each subject appears in the answer. Then use get the most popular subject using the max function with a lambda comparator to keep it clean.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

subject_count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for ind, student in students.items():
    subject = student['subject']
    subject_count[subject] += 1

print(max(subject_count.items(), key=lambda a: a[1]))
```

Comment: this is a very bad answer, in the sense that you are talking to a newbie (the code itself is okay). At least explain what this code does please.

Comment: I would have used a `defaultdict` here.

Comment: @Derlin, I'm sorry, I pressed Enter as I was writing the answer and it got posted before I could finish it.

Comment: I understand, happens to me all the time. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Interesting data structure, yes defaultdict would be better here.